# JavaFX application shows weird symbols instead Russian language

Tags: java, javafx, localization

I'm developing application and everything is okay. 
Application suppose to support English and Russian. 
English works fine, but when I am trying start app with Russian locale I see this:

https://yadi.sk/i/gj8TOziskGvzf

I load language from bundle, in `start()` method:

```
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ru", "RU"));
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("view/sample.fxml"));
    loader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.MyBundle"));
```

In Controller:

```
public class SingleSiteConfiguratorController implements Initializable {
    //....
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        this.languageBundle = resourceBundle;
    }
   //....
   // And accessing
   private void someMethod() {
       String outputDir = languageBundle.getString("choose_output_folder");
   }
}
```

And in `MyBandle_ru.properties`:

```
#...
choose_output_folder=Выберите папку в которой сгенерируется приложение
#...
```

What is wrong?

Comment: A Java Properties file [must be in the ISO-8859-1 encoding.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-)  IDEs have a tendency to “hide” this by showing `\u` escapes as their corresponding characters.  The only way to know for sure is to open it in a plain text editor.  You may find the JDK's [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html) tool useful for creating your .properties file with the proper escapes.

Comment: @VGR you are right. Thank you. Intellij saves it in UTF-8 (File->Settings>Files Encoding) and I haven't find method to convert `*.properties` file. So I just have used online service to convert  http://native2ascii.net/# and it worked. Please post answer to this question

Comment: But now I have another issue sometimes I see this: `invalid next size (fast): 0x00007f71984bf9b0 ***` (if persist will post another question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Java Properties file [must be in the ISO-8859-1 encoding.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-)  IDEs have a tendency to “hide” this by showing `\u` escapes as their corresponding characters.  The only way to know for sure is to open it in a plain text editor.

You may find the JDK's [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html) tool useful for creating your .properties file with the proper escapes.